# ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported

Tags: cassandra, cql, nosql

I am using cassandra 2.1 with latest CQL.

Here is my table & indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE mydata.chats_new (
    id bigint,
    adid bigint,
    fromdemail text,
    fromemail text,
    fromjid text,
    messagebody text,
    messagedatetime text,
    messageid text,
    messagetype text,
    todemail text,
    toemail text,
    tojid text,
    PRIMARY KEY(messageid,messagedatetime)
);



CREATE INDEX user_fromJid ON mydata.chats_new (fromjid);
CREATE INDEX user_toJid ON mydata.chats_new (tojid);
CREATE INDEX user_adid ON mydata.chats_new (adid);
```

When i execute this query:

```
select * from chats_new WHERE fromjid='test' AND toJid='test1' ORDER BY messagedatetime DESC;
```

I got this error:

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported."
```

So how should fetch this data?

Comment: Secondary indexes are not intended to allow you to query the same table 4 different ways.  What you *should* do, is build 3 additional query tables (chats_new_by_fromjid, chats_new_by_tojid, chats_new_by_adid) and key those tables to support the queries that you have in-mind.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 OK, but in this case `messagedatetime` is the clustering key (right?) so Cassandra should be able to `ORDER BY` it anyway.

Comment: @Raedwald Yes, the clustering key still takes effect.  But as a secondary index query pulls back data from multiple partitions, it may or may not come back in sorted order (which is why `ORDER BY` is not allowed on secondary index queries).

Answer (score 9):

```
select * from chats_new 
WHERE fromjid='test' AND toJid='test1' 
ORDER BY messagedatetime DESC;
```

> code=2200 [Invalid query] message="ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported."

To get the WHERE clause of this query to work, I would build a specific query table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mydata.chats_new_by_fromjid_and_tojid (
    id bigint,
    adid bigint,
    fromdemail text,
    fromemail text,
    fromjid text,
    messagebody text,
    messagedatetime text,
    messageid text,
    messagetype text,
    todemail text,
    toemail text,
    tojid text,
    PRIMARY KEY((fromjid, tojid), messagedatetime, messageid)
);
```

Note the primary key definition.  This creates a partitioning key out of `fromjid` and `tojid`.  While this will allow you to query on both fields, it will also *require* both fields to be specified in all queries on this table.  But that's why they call it a "query table", as it is generally designed to serve one particular query.

As for the remaining fields in the primary key, I kept `messagedatetime` as the first clustering column, to assure on-disk sort order.  Default ordering in Cassandra is ascending, so if you want to change that at query time, that's where your `ORDER BY messagedatetime DESC` comes into play.  And lastly, I made sure that the `messageid` was the second clustering column, to help ensure primary key uniqueness (assuming that `messageid` is unique).

Now, this query will work:

```
select * from chats_new_by_fromjid_and_tojid 
WHERE fromjid='test' AND toJid='test1'
ORDER BY messagedatetime DESC;
```

If you need to query this data by additional criteria, I highly recommend that you create additional query table(s).  Remember, Cassandra works best with tables that are specifically designed for each query they serve.  It's ok to replicate your data a few times, because disk space is cheap...operation time is not.

Also, DataStax has a great article on [when *not* to use a secondary index](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html?scroll=concept_ds_sgh_yzz_zj__when-no-index).  It's definitely worth a read.

Comment: There is a way to paginate this results? (In the way that you have order it, my fromjid and toJid has the same values.)

Comment: @CBox Assuming you know the desired split values ahead of time, you should be able to accomplish that with the `token()` function for a specific partitioning key range: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html

Comment: Yes the problem is how to know them ahead of time :) do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @CBox It depends on your data.  But you can start by looking at your partitioning key values directly (`SELECT DISTINCT fromjid FROM chats_new_by_fromjid_and_tojid;` for the above example).

Comment: What the distinct gives me? I've try it didn't see anything helpful, Are you open for Modeling job?

Comment: @CBox `DISTINCT` should give you your partitioning keys, which should allow to you better-evaluate your data for proper paging splits.  And "no" I'm not interested in a job.

Comment: Aren't `PRIMARY KEY`s unique? Meaning that a `WHERE fromjid='test' AND toJid='test1'` is going to return exactly **one** row? In other words, the `ORDER BY` is rendered totally useless. Am I missing something?

Comment: @alexiswilke the *complete* PRIMARY KEY definition is `PRIMARY KEY((fromjid, tojid), messagedatetime, messageid)`, so in this case multiple rows will be returned for the different values of `messagedatetime` and `messageid`.